# How do I avoid Source Formatter from Unfolding XML Documentations?

Tags: delphi, xml-documentation

Just a tiny question, every time I fold an XML document, I then click `Ctrl-D` (Format Source) and then it Unfolds them. How can I disable that? (I don't think there's an option for this, is there?)

Thanks all.

Comment: FWIW For XML editing I use the free FirstObject XML Editor (FOXE) http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm maybe that's a solution for you (with copy/paste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option for doing so. It's a known issue that formatting does not respect the folded sections of code (it doesn't restore them to the folded state after doing it's work). The solution appears to be to format the code yourself. :-) It's been discussed previously in the Embarcadero IDE forums since the formatter was added to the IDE.

Comment: is it fixed in XE3 ? i seriously hate Embacadero for not fixing known simple bugs in their IDE, wth is going on with them...

Comment: @user1803300: My first sentence says "there's no option for doing so.". If it was fixed in XE3, I would have said so. :-) I'll try again, though: "There's no option to stop this from happening. It's been a problem since formatting was added to the IDE." I also think it's a minor issue, not a major one. If the formatter not preserving code folding bothers you, use it once, fix your folding, and then don't use it again and format your code as you type it. :-)